# MySQL: INSERT all columns form one table into another table based on column in third table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

Okay- I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but what I'm after is this:

We have tables for terminated employees (employees_term) and training history (traininghistory) and training history for terminated employees for archiving (traininghistory_term).

I need to INSERT all of the columns from traininghistory into traininghistory_term based on the employee number in the employees_term table (so it only copies over the terminated employees and not the active employees).  I need to run this one time to copy over all of our terminated employees training info and don't want to build an entire function for something that I'll use once and I know MySQL can do with a couple lines.

traininghistory_term is an EXACT copy of traininghistory- literally copied the table structure and all.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
INSERT INTO traininghistory_term SELECT * FROM traininghistory
JOIN employees_term
    ON employees_term.employee_id = traininghistory.EMPID
```

And here's what MySQL is telling me:
`#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SELECT traininghistory.* FROM ...`—you're currently also selecting all the columns from `employees_term`.

Comment: Oi.  I knew I was missing something stupid easy.  Thanks!

Comment: @eggyal: good catch.  Thanks!  re:—you're currently also selecting all the columns from employees_term